# Rules for the use of roman numerals in portuguese

Tags: ortografia, números

I know that commonly, the roman numerals are used to refer to a date or, more precisely, to a specific century, like in the examples below:

> - Aconteceu no século XX;
> - Um dos livros mais importantes do século XVIII;

I'd like to know if there is some rule to use this type of number in portuguese. Should they just be used to talk about a century or is this just a convention?

Can I use it to say something like "*Eu tenho X anos*" or not?

Comment: 'Talk', na última linha, está incorreto. Sugiro a substituição por 'say', por exemplo.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Eu tentei, mas a edição era demasiado pequena para ser permitida pelo sistema. Não tive paciência para contornar isto.

Comment: It's just like English. No difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### I'd like to know if there is some rule to use this type of number in portuguese. They are only allowed to talk about a century or this is just a convention?

Yes, there's a rule. Usually, roman numerals are used for:

- Centuries;
- King/Pope Names;
- Parts of a book or written piece, like a play script;

Additionally, the spoken rule is:

- Until the tenth numeral, is an **ordinal** numeral:

  > No *capítulo II* (**capítulo segundo**), estudamos fonema e letra.
- After the tenth numeral, is a **cardinal** numeral:

  > O *volume XII* (**volume doze**) desta coleção traz biografias de pintores.

**Exception**: if numeral comes **before** the substantive, is spoken **always** as an **ordinal** number:

> O *XI capítulo* (**décimo primeiro capítulo**) pareceu-me mais longo.

### Can I use it to talk something like *Eu tenho X anos*. Or not?

No, for this case it is wrong.

Comment: Em vez de "Exception: if numeral comes before the substantive, is spoken always as a cardinal number: O XI capítulo (décimo primeiro capítulo) pareceu-me mais longo." deve ser: "Exception: if numeral comes before the substantive, is spoken always as an ordinal number: O XI capítulo (décimo primeiro capítulo) pareceu-me mais longo."

Comment: @AméricoTavares Obrigado! Confundi na hora de escrever.

Comment: Não é regra. São costumes.

Answer (score 7):

No.

See [this link](http://professorthiagolira.blogspot.com.br/2010/05/numerais-algarismo-romano.html):

It should be used to refer to

- Centuries, like "*As grandes navegações ocorreram nos séculos XV e XVI.*"
- Book or films chapters, volumes, parts or some other division, like "*Veja mais informações no Capítulo V.*" or "*Episódio VI: O retorno de Jedi*".
- Popes, kings and emperor names, like "*O papa Bento XVI renunciou.*", or "*O imperador Dom Pedro II governou o Brasil por 49 anos.*"